# Send an unsolicited message to Discord channel using nodejs

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Looking for a way to send completely unsolicited messages to my discord channel using [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/).

Background: I have a nodejs app running on my desktop that is monitoring a few websites and I need to notify my team so they can deal with things as the problem evolves. It's an ongoing issue which I'm not getting into right now. Yes, I want to pay for a pro website monitor, but the bean-counters yadda yadda...

I've read through the docs but it seems everything is geared towards event-driven behaviour from the discord side e.g. a new user arrives, a typed command is entered etc

I don't want that. I just want to send a notification when the server that I'm monitoring does X thing.

Here is what I have so far:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

config.discord.client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

if(shitgoesdown){
    new Discord.Message(config.discord.client, data, config.discord.channel);
}
```

I can't seem to find anything on how to just point this thing at my server. The docs are great and all but they are super dense and right now it's just information overload. If someone could just point at the sign that would be great.

Comment: Can't you just do something like `client.channels.cache.get('ID').send("something happened")`

Comment: Does the server you are monitoring do something noticeable? Are you in control of the server you are monitoring?

Comment: Monitoring the server is not the issue. That part is all good. Messages to Discord all I care about.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the channel using `client.channels.fetch(/* Channel ID */)` and send a message in the callback using `channel.send()`.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

// Code to execute when something happens
client.channels.fetch(/* Channel ID */).then(channel => {
  channel.send('Some message');
});
```

Comment: Oh ok... so is the channel ID universally unique? Or do I need to tell the client about my server first?

Comment: @BitShift Yes, they are unique. The bot must be on the servers the channels are on though so that it can access them.

Comment: ah ok there's the catch... I knew this all seemed a bit weird. Thanks man looks like what I need might not be possible and probably a good thing too for security reasons.

Comment: @BitShift Why wouldn't it be possible? Do you know how to get a bot on a server?

Comment: Nope but if that's possible (which it looks like it is) then I'll try that and report back with an answer. This all makes a lot more sense now thanks again!